# What is the fine line between time series data anlysis and time series data mining?

Tags: terminology, time-series-analysis

I am trying to do thesis work in Computer science and the data mining in time series is the relevant theme, however the analysis of time series is not (it is mathematics subject). What is the fine line? Analysis is about discovery and parameter estimation of the (stochastic) model of time series, but it seems to me that data mining should do the same as well, isn't it? What is the difference and how not to cross the line? Maybe data mining ir more general than analysis, because it handles also logical models, association rules, etc.?

Comment: http://edoc.hu-berlin.de/master/kleist-caroline-2015-03-25/PDF/kleist.pdf is excellent introductory review and there is very few statistics indeed.

Comment: Who told you one was in and the other out of scope? Ask *them*!